# Ruby on Rails ERB multiple items form select without sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, erb

For example in .erb file.

```
<%= f.select(:animals, animals_for_select_tag, {}, { multiple: true, include_blank: false}) %>
```

The items in drop down list, i.e. animals_for_select_tag are ordered in alphabetical order as shown below:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'mouse', 'panther', 'zebra']
```

Let's say I want to select items  `mouse`, `panther`, and `dog`, in this particular order. However, what I get is always sorted in order of `dog`, `mouse`, `panther`.

Reference:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Is there any way for selection in custom order?

Comment: I think you can use `options_for_select([['Dog', 'dog'], ['Mouse', 'mouse'], ['Cat', 'cat']])`. with select tag.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You want the select as it is currently but you want the values in the order user have selected them correct?

Comment: How is stored the order?

Comment: @Manishh Yes you are right. I want the order of selected items as is, while the drop down list items stay the same order.

Comment: @iGian The order of drop down list items were sorted alphabetically.

Comment: is it necessary to have select? you may use http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ it has auto complete and can send data in sequence.